# openjdk 8 GC mechanism

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am using openjdk version 1.8.0_202 and below are JVM GC params

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_202"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_202-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)



-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=25 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=15 -XX:-ResizePLAB -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:ConcGCThreads=8 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20
```

memory has given as

-Xmx10g -Xms10g

I have observed that during load GC is happening at around 60% of heap utilization. However, when load is not running GC is happening at around 75%.

My concern is why it is going till 75% ? and How much beyond (80% or 90% or 95%) it can go ? Can someone pls help ?

Comment: Can someone pls help ?

Comment: Does this cause any problems for you, or are you just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: As the G1 is a generational GC if I remember correctly, it could just be that the lifetime of objects allocated with and without load is different (e.g. more short-lived objects with load), leading to different distribution of heap memory across the young/old generations. You could try to learn whats going on by activating more detailed GC logs (see e.g. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html), or with a memory profiler.

Comment: @Hulk: As of now it doesn't cause any problem but if it goes up to 95% then it is a point of concern as i dont know if it goes till 100% may be

Comment: How did you come to the memory/GC parameters you listed in your question? Settings like these need quite some expert knowledge about the GC. Especially setting the max. stack size to 10GB is rarely necessary. Did you have stack overflows with a smaller stack size? Deep recursions? Huge number of threads?

Comment: It has always been a typical behaviour of the JVM to use a big percentage of the max heap memory, even if most of the memory used contains garbage (I believe that reduces the GC overhead). You should only be concerned if it reaches 100% AND experiences performance degradation due to GCs not freeing enough memory. The percentage alone is no indicator of concern.

Comment: What are “during load” and “when load is not running” supposed to mean?

Comment: @Holger : Load I meant is traffic to the application.  If traffic is not coming ( as it is in controlled environment in testing phase so we can control sending traffic / request to the application) then GC is happening at 75% of total heap utilization. If traffic is coming then we are observing GC is happening at 60%. As it is going till 75% in the case mentioned so my concern is can it go beyond 75% as well ? If no, it is ok with me. But if yes, then how much beyond 75% memory can go to hit GC.

Comment: @Ralf Kleberhoff: I understand your point. However, my concern is can it go till 100% as well ? Traffic is running from last many days so i  am observing  GC is happening at approx 60% of memory utilization. If Traffic is not running then GC is happening at approx 75%. As I am observing it from last many days so I am sure that memory leak is not there. However, from GC behavior point of view I want to understand can memory go beyond 75% as well and than GC will trigger ? If yes, can it go till 95% as well ?

Comment: So what you’re saying is, when the load is high, the GC starts earlier, perfectly compensating the higher load, but for some reason, you’re worrying that the GC could happen later?